# "hostname is too long" error messages in PowerShell when running a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, ip, hostname

```
$IPadd = get-content LRSHost.txt
foreach ($ip in $IPadd) {
  [system.net.dns]::gethostentry("$IPAdd")
}
```

When running this I get this error:

> the size of hostname is too long. it cannot be longer than 255 characters

The IP addresses on the text file are in the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` format, there is one IP address per line.

I tried replacing `[system.net.dns]::gethostentry("$IPAdd")` with `write-host $ip`, to check for how Powershell was processing each IP, and the IP addressess show properly on the screen. I tried removing the quotes on `$IPAdd`, I added quotes on the text file, same error message.

Any help you can provide I would appreciate it.

Comment: try this instead `[system.net.dns]::gethostbyaddress($ip)`

Answer (score 0):

You made a trivial mistake. The line inside the loop should be:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ip)
```

Right now you were trying to pass whole `$IPadd` file content instead of single `$ip`. Also, quotes around a lone variable aren't needed - I'd recommend reading further about [variable substitution/interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.3#variable-substitution).